# using Map to get object of custom class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new at using maps, how can we get object of custom Class from Map..

i.e.
feedSendModelClass:

```
public class feedSendModelClass {
private String content;
private String picThumbnail;
private String picurl;
private String videourl;
private String videoThumbnail;
private String mTime;



public feedSendModelClass() {
    //blank for firebase
}

public String getTime() {
    return mTime;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    mTime = time;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getVideoThumbnail() {
    return videoThumbnail;
}

public void setVideoThumbnail(String videoThumbnail) {
    this.videoThumbnail = videoThumbnail;
}

public String getVideourl() {
    return videourl;
}

public void setVideourl(String videourl) {
    this.videourl = videourl;
}

public String getPicurl() {
    return picurl;
}

public void setPicurl(String picurl) {
    this.picurl = picurl;
}

public String getPicThumbnail() {
    return picThumbnail;
}

public void setPicThumbnail(String picThumbnail) {
    this.picThumbnail = picThumbnail;
}
}
```

Map

```
Map<String, feedSendModelClass> feedKeys = (Map<String,feedSendModelClass>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

Datasnapshot:

```
DataSnapshot { key = feedsMetaPool, value = {20160708155218759={content=bzzzhss, picurl=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rootssahaj.appspot.com/o/feedsImages%2FnonThumbs%2F201607081552353353553518759sahaj9917730102?alt=media&token=ce1c6e7c-28c5-442e-9405-4468bf5fc204, time=08 Jul, picThumbnail=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rootssahaj.appspot.com/o/feedsImages%2Fthumbs%2F20353353535355353160708155218759sahaj9917730102?alt=media&token=14d33963-f3da-4407-a08f-ab0afce21ace}, 20160708164100152={content=sj sjs skss sksssvsjm, picurl=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rootssahaj.appspot.com/o/feedsImages%2FnonThumbs%2F201607081641003535152sahaj9917730102?alt=media&token=323c4a27-1850-4bc9-adea-34e5319ac506, time=08 Jul, picThumbnail=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rootssahaj.appspot.com/o/feedsImages%2Fthumbs%2F20160708164100152sahaj9917730102?alt=media&token=0b064b46-2f14-49af-b3e6-7a573f6c2d3f}, 20160708142314069={content=dadax, picurl=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rootssahaj.appspot.com/o/feedsImages%2FnonThumbs%2F2016070rdgdg54353535358142314069sahaj9917730102?alt=media&token=19d03f11-d12f-43c1-96f5-ca397a9179c9, time=08 Jul, picThumbnail=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rootssahaj.appspot.com/o/feedsImages%2Fthumbs%2F20160735353508142314069sahaj9917730102?alt=media&token=ab9c73eb-ec44-46ae-9daa-6fc508cb08a6} }
```

This has become tricky for me..Thanks..
There could be some other way round to do it through firebase

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how you retrieve the `feedSendModelClass` object from the map named `feedKeys`, then this syntax should work:

```
feedKeys.get(key)
```

The `key` is your String, and the object is the `feedSendModelClass` object. However, first you'd need to put key and value pairs into the map (so it's not empty), with `feedKeys.put(key, value)`, where the key is a `String` and value is the `feedSendModelClass`.

If this totally doesn't answer your question, I apologize, but from your description, it is a bit difficult to understand what you need help with.

On an unrelated note, it would be more appropriate to name your class `FeedSendModelClass`, as per Java conventions classes start with a capital letter.

Comment: actually the key would be not known to me.. So I wanted to know i f there is a way to get Object.

Comment: If the key isn't known to you, I don't think there is much point in using a Map. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I want to get the data of DataSnapshot into the object of feed Class

Comment: What do you mean by "data" of DataSnapshot? It's value? I'm assuming you will have multiple instances of these kinds of data. How do you plan to retrieve them? It is a bit unclear to me what you want to do with this data. If you just want to store it somehow in the feed object, an arrayList would work. If you need to access the data more specifically, try to elaborate.

Comment: I mean DataSnapshot is a json data and from which I need the value of key (let it be)`20160708155218759` and then i will put it in object of that Class and as I'm using Listener interface, the object would return to me n then I will put it in Recycler view's adapter

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firebase then you can use a `ChildEventListener`. It calls the `onChildAdded()` method once for every initial child in the node and everytime a new child is added. Then you can add the Object to an ArrayList directly (or do whatever you want with it)

```
ArrayList<feedSendModelClass> feedKeysArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

DatabaseReference feedKeysRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("path/to/the/feedkeys");
feedKeysRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            feedKeysArrayList.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(feedSendModelClass.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            // Add appropriate code
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Add appropriate code
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            // Add appropriate code
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Add appropriate code
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for help!  I got it correct btw i knew it.. I was just trying to make a short process of query..